# Understand batch variable reference %ABC_VERSION:V=%

Tags: batch-file

Sorry for this simple question, but I have little experience in batch and I failed to find any answer by Google.

I notice that in a batch file, the variable `ABC_VERSION` whose value is `v8.0.3` is referenced as `%ABC_VERSION:V=%`. What does it mean by referencing this variable in this weird format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is to remove the 'V' if it exists. This is documented in the help for the SET command. See SET /?

Comment: Could you give me more details? I can't see how this is related to the SET command...

Comment: You need to scroll down to about the 4th page of the help found when you do SET /?. Typically this is used with SET, but it can also be used with ECHO. What it means is  that the character string after the : and before the = is to be replaced by the character string after the =. Which in your case means to replace the V with nothing.

Comment: Nice! I see the explaination for `%PATH:str1=str2%` in the manual. Thanks:)